# Displayport connected monitor blinks Blue on Sleep?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, sleep, displayport

I have a triple monitor setup.

3 BenQ 27" LEDs (same model, GW2760HS) connected to a 1050 GTX via DVI, HDMI and Displayport.

The one that's connected via Displayport (DP to HDMI cable), every time the computer goes to sleep, it doesn't just go to black like the other monitors. Instead, it goes to black, then to bright blue, back to black, back and forth within approx 10 seconds intervals.

Q: How do I make it not do that? I just want it to go to black, not blink blue.

Using Windows 7 Home Ed.

Comment: Are all 3 monitors the same type too?

Comment: Correct. They're all the same BenQ GW2760HS

Comment: Have you tried plugging the Display Port cable into another monitor? Could be the cable that's broken somewhere, or it might be the low power state of sleep mode

Comment: Plugging it into one of the other ones was one of the ideas I thought about, I'll give it a try thanks for your reply.

Comment: Interesting. When I switched the cables, the monitor that used the DP went full blue, and said "No cable connected", while the other one went full black and said the same thing. Which leads me to believe it might not be the cable that's the issue. There's also an option in my monitor that says "Light Blue Light", I open the menu and there's a bunch of options, percentage numbers, for "Reading", "Multimedia" etc. Not sure what those are about. Could be the blue light intensity. No option to disable it. I never messed with this stuff before I don't know why it's on. FWIW the cable is DP to HDMI

Comment: Hmm one of the monitors behave differently when it comes to that settings. In one of them, if I open that Blue Light menu and hit the back key, it looks like it turns it off. Not for the other ones, which I had to do a "Reset All" to disable it. Let's see if that fixes it!

Comment: @TCrumpen looks like that setting has nothing to do with it. After swapping cables, the other monitor started blue blinking on sleep and the previous one stopped. So it is definitely the DP cable. I don't know if it's cause of the 'cable' itself, or the 'DP' portion of it.